Как сделать исключение, если ответ не найден? (пайтон)
Я написал ИИ по туториалу (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deploy-a-chatbot-using-tensorflow-in-python), как можно сделать так, чтобы если ИИ не нашел ответ на вопрос, то писал "Я не могу ответить на данный вопрос"? Т.к. если он его не находит, то пишет "Hello". Менять ERROR_THRESHOLD нету смысла, так как у "hello" и "влытомлтмлвтмлат" одинаковый probability. Заранее спасибо.

Хм, в коде по приведённой вами ссылке нет никакого hello, откуда оно берётся? В том коде можно просто поменять result = "" прописав тут нужную вам фразу. Если вероятности всех интентов будут меньше фрешолда, вернётся этот заранее заданный результат и что там пропишете, то и будет выведено.

По ссылке есть "hello" как пример (в файле intense.json.). Насчёт result = ... - я пробовал, но дело в том, что у "превет" и "ыотдмлвыатмлоы" одинаковый probability, поэтому либо ИИ будет отвечать "hello" на неизвестные вопросы, либо будет выдавать ошибку при малейшей опечатке (как в примере с "превет").
